# Purpose of [prisoner]

Tags: discussion, tags

> *Please note that voting has moved here:*
>
> ## [Tag for prisoner puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/tag-for-prisoner-puzzles)

A new tag has sprung up, namely the [prisoner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prisoner) tag. At the moment, it contains one question, but a [suggested edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32331) to add that tag was declined.

Though it does class a particular type of puzzles, the setting is rather restricted (since similar puzzles can be set without prisoners and still be equivalent). My concern is that with the current name the tag doesn't mean more than could be achieved by searching for "warden" or "prisoner".

Regarding that point, maybe something like [limited-information](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-information) proposed by [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) on the [aforementioned question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/tag-for-prisoner-puzzles) might work as a better general tag.

> What would the purpose and the scope of the [prisoner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prisoner) tag be, and why do we need it?
> Should we keep the tag, and if so should the tag be named something else?

As an offside, most of our tags are plurals. Should this tag be renamed [prisoners](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prisoners) if community decides it is fine anyway?

Comment: +1 for taking this to meta, even though I don't agree with the tag.

Comment: I've hopefully captured the essence of the discussion points here in the various new answers to the original [Tag for prisoner puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4548/30633) question - please comment on and/or vote for one of the answers there, or add your own answer if desired.

Answer (score 12):

**I don't think we need this tag.**

Although I'm willing to be convinced if you can elaborate on this:

> it does class a particular type of puzzles

**What type of puzzles?** As far as I can see, it describes a particular *context* in which puzzles can be set, which doesn't equate to a type of puzzle. Flavour text is most often irrelevant, and puzzles about prisoners could be [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) (e.g. [Four prisoners wearing black and white hats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1980/5373)) or [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) (e.g. [The Honest Guard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25641/5373)) or [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) ("you are a prisoner and must solve this riddle to escape") or [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) (e.g. [Stargate escape](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/44739/5373)) or ... well, almost any type of puzzle. The fact that the puzzle is about prisoners doesn't really seem to be useful information.

Or, to put it [another way](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32341):

> This [tag does] not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is *about*, not just what it *contains*.

---

<sub>As an aside, it's not true that most of our tags have plural names. See [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle), [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher), [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle), [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern), [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme), [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle), [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story), [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence), [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus), [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle), etc. etc. and also the previous meta post [Renaming the "crosswords" tag to "crossword", and other such tag pluralizations](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/5373), especially the new answer from @Alconja.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am also against the tag, and what I meant to say is that I believe that its intention was to class a particular type of puzzle. Thanks for pulling me up on the pluralisation fact as well.

Comment: I've hopefully captured the essence of the discussion points here in the various new answers to the original [Tag for prisoner puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4548/30633) question - please comment on and/or vote for one of the answers there, or add your own answer if desired.

Comment: @Rubio Might I suggest CW status for the answers which are essentially just copied from other people's comments/answers? (Or are you trying to get a tag badge in [meta-tag:discussion]? :-P )

Answer (score 4):

Besides from [limited-information](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-information) I could imagine that a [cooperation-game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooperation-game) tag would describe that class of puzzles quite well. It would be

> [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) $\supset$ [cooperation-game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooperation-game) $\supset$ [hat-guessing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hat-guessing).

A possible description for that tag is:
*A puzzle about finding a strategy involving several individuals cooperating to achieve a common aim. Examples are prisoners trying to avoid an execution, a group of people trying to guess the colors of their hats, or a magician and his assistants.*

Comment: I believe that that would be a useful tag, maybe you should make this into a separate meta post and see what people say.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and probably addresses the spirit of what was originally intended for the "prisoner" tag.

Comment: I like this idea a lot! What about [team-strategy] for the tag name?

Answer (score 0):

Well well ...

I commented (as a joke) under the [only question that is with the tag now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59412/who-killed-the-indiscriminate-warden) that "It is time to add a tag 'prisoner', or 'warden'."

I didn't expect that someone *really* added such a tag.

I mistakenly thought that since the tag is added, it is deemed appropriate and I suggested the edit mentioned by OP because I think the question is no less irrelevant than the one already with the tag ...

Well, so much for history. Here are some of my ideas. It does not have to exist in the first place, and if it does, I expect the description to be (**besides** what is already mentioned in A.P.'s answer).

> A puzzle that involves making decision in a dilemma that would normally be deemed inhumane.

(Give the wrong answer and you have to die? Probably doesn't make much sense outside the context of puzzling)

Anyway, I appreciate many of the suggestions in the linked question and have upvoted them.